# Where to put babel setting in lerna setup as it is not recognizing jsx code in shared code directory

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader, lerna

I have used lerna to setup the repo.
This is the error I am getting - [image: Error]

This error is coming in the shared code which I have put in the components directory. Below is my directory structure.

[image: directory structure-1]

[image: directory structure-2][image: directory structure-3]

So I have this Button component to be used in both the apps. After seeing the error it seems to me it's not recognizing the jsx syntax and asking for **@babel/preset-react** . So what I tried is I tried to create **.babelrc** file inside buttons folder with this content -

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

and then additionaly I also created one **webpack.config.js** file inside buttons folder with this content -

```
module.exports = {
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            loader: "babel-loader"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

This doesn't helped me!
I also tried to create **babel.config.js** in the root folder with a few contents copied but it didn't work.
I have separate **.babelrc** and **webpack.config.js** files in both the apps inside the apps folder as shown in the snapshot. When I am using **buttons** as a dependency in package.json in apps and then using it, then this error is coming. I don't know how to resolve this issue. Any help will be greatly appreciated.
[This is example repo I have created for reference](https://github.com/Faizahmadfaiz/lerna-webapp)

Comment: Can you try `"presets": ["@babel/env", "@babel/react"]`?

Comment: @RRK For @babel/env and @babel/react it's showing **Not Found: @babel/react@latest** as I checked both libraries are not in npm packages. Without installing also I checked but it's the same error. Not recognizing jsx code. Also if this would have worked then also this will be not an optimal solution as for every component I will create, I have to create **.bebelrc** and *webpack.config.js*. I think there should be some setup in root folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to get this to work might be to nail the babel config straight into the webpack configuration:

In your case you have to change the babel-loader config so it will look like that:

```
{
    test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: {
      loader: "babel-loader",
      options: {
        presets: [
          "@babel/preset-react",
        ],
      }
    }
  },
```

I just tried it on your test repo for app2 and it works

Comment: Inside **webpack.config.js** file inside **buttons**, I put this code-
`
module.exports = {
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            loader: "babel-loader",
            options: {
              presets: [
                "@babel/preset-react"
              ]
            },
          }
        }
      ]
    }
}  
`
and deleted *.babelrc* from there. It doesn't work. There should be some way to put things in root directory so it can cater for any future component added

Comment: It's irrelevant where you put the webpack file, as long it is the file being used. Please refer to webpack documentation and babel-loader documentation, it's quite good. I assume you have some kind of structural mess in your project, happens to all of us. If you need more help please share your repo or any minimal example

Comment: I have created this repo with a minimal example. All the structure and setup is the exact replica of my actual repo. [https://github.com/Faizahmadfaiz/lerna-webapp](https://github.com/Faizahmadfaiz/lerna-webapp)

Comment: seems like it's something with the babel config for the buttons module. I tried also moving babelrc files around, since you didn't have one for the buttons module, but that didn't solve the issue. Anyways, I've changed my answer so it's better suited to your project